# dts-generator vs dts-bundle. Which one is better?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I am trying to generate a single typescript definition file for my typescript project which contains several base/inherit classes, utilities, etc. In our project, each A.ts file will be compiled to A.js file, A.js.map file, and A.d.ts. After research, I found both tools can help me to bundle those d.ts file into a single d.ts file. Does anyone use them before? Which one is better?

Comment: There is another one https://www.npmjs.com/package/dts-bundle-generator. Possible it will useful for you too.

Answer (score 0):

**dts-generator** worked better for me out of the two. However, I would suggest to also have a look at **npm-dts**. npm-dts adds index.d.ts file to TS-based npm package so it could be consumed out of the box by other TS modules and have code suggestions even if src is not included with it.

If you use "npm-dts", you do not need to generate declarations for each A.ts - it will crawl your project and generate typings on its own.

Command line usage looks something like this:

```
npm-dts -r /your/project/root generate
```

Note that it expects root to contain package.json file. Also, your project has to have node modules installed with "TypeScript" among them.

Hope this helps.